# Objective C - can't set value in one method and access it from another

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I am trying to do the following:

1) user clicks button **start**, it runs `startTimer` method, which sets a new `[NSDate date]`.

2) user clicks button **stop** it runs `stopTimer` method, which retrieves the `[NSDate date]` value.

I can't get step number 2 working. I've set it in the `.h` file.  If I copy the code from the start method into the stop method it works.  So, I can set the `[NSDate date]`.  But, this is not what I want.  I want to be able to set it in the `startTimer` method. How do i go about this?

**.h file**

```
@interface StartTest : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *timer;

    NSDate *startNSDate;
    NSDate *start;



}

- (IBAction)startTimer;
- (IBAction)stopTimer;

- (NSDate *)setStart;
- (NSDate *)getStart;


@end
```

**.m file:**

```
@implementation Ash

- (IBAction)startTimer {

    startNSDate = [NSDate date];

}


- (IBAction)stopTimer{

    start = [NSDate date];


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];


    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:startNSDate]; // <<< this is where it fails

    NSLog(@"stringfromdate: %@", stringFromDate);
}
```

Comment: i get this error: `Thread 1: Program recieved signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the line in startTimer where i have startNSDate

Comment: i can set a varaible (if it is a NSString) in startTimer and retrieve it in stopTimer - is there any special thing i have to do with NSDate?

Comment: Why is the name in @ interface and @ implement different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startNSDate isn't retained and by the time you want to access it, it's already dealloc'd, hence you're trying to access garbage pointer

easiest solution for you will be

```
@interface StartTest : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *timer;

    NSDate *startNSDate;
    NSDate *start;



}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* startNSDate;

- (IBAction)startTimer;
- (IBAction)stopTimer;

- (NSDate *)setStart;
- (NSDate *)getStart;


@end




@implementation Ash

- (IBAction)startTimer {

    self.startNSDate = [NSDate date];

}


- (IBAction)stopTimer{

    start = [NSDate date];


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

    // this is where it fails, the reason being that startNSDate isn't retained
    // and by this line, it's already dealloc'd, hence you're trying to access
    // garbage pointer
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter self.startNSDate]; 

    NSLog(@"stringfromdate: %@", stringFromDate);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.startNSDate = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```